# Async Socket IO

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous

To refresh and expand my C++ knowledge I am trying to implement a fcgi application and implement the fcgi interface myself. However, I have no expierience using sockets. Research has lead me to Boost.asio, but with my lack of socket knowledge I find it hard to use the library by the tutorials, which are sometimes only code examples, and browsing an apireference when you do not know what you are looking for is difficult.

Questions:

1. Which Tutorial(Other than the one coming wiht boost.asio)/Book would you recommend to read up on sockets/asynchronus IO?
2. For fcgi I find it hard to understand the benefits of AsyncIO, the header has to be decode first and then the data can be received, how does one get benefits by asynchronus I/O?
3. Is there some heuristic to know which parameters (number of threads, sockets per thread, socket multiplexing(yes(how many connections?)/no, async IO, buffersize) yield thebest performance for an fcgi interface?

Comment: Do you have a platform in mind? Or must this be totally platform agnostic?

Comment: check out [0mq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) for a nice intro into the perils and solutions when using sockets. You might even find zeromq easy to start with.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Good suggestion, it's the way I'd go from scratch for a job. It depends what he's trying to learn I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend (for free) [BeeJs networking guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) or (for pay) [W Richard Stevens book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Unix-Network-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0131411551/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1395651473&sr=1-2&keywords=network%20programming) on sockets.

AIO (in this case) is a method of multiplexing multiple connections. If you don't have multiple connections you won't see any benefit. It's also the fastest though hardest method for doing this task. The idea is that any individual read or write to a connection may take time just waiting for resources to be available. AIO allows your application to move on to another connection and service that whilst it waits for those resources. In short, your app spends more time working and less time waiting, over multiple connections.

No. It depends on your architecture and your expected load. Really clever web servers will adjust all of that based on configuration and also on measured usage.